# Internationalization with Hasura and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hasura

I am struggling with internationalization with Hasura and PostgreSQL.

I have the following tables right now:

cms

| **created_at (timestamp)** | **updated_at (timestamp)** | **slug (text)** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 075cb5f4-241a-4624-b3ed-eafae12567d3 | 2023-05-25T08:49:25.945023+00:00 | 2023-05-25T08:49:25.945023+00:00 |

cms_translations

| **language (text)** | **attribute (text)** | **translation (text)** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 075cb5f4-241a-4624-b3ed-eafae12567d3 | bg | title |
| 075cb5f4-241a-4624-b3ed-eafae12567d3 | bg | body |
| 075cb5f4-241a-4624-b3ed-eafae12567d3 | bg | tags |
| 075cb5f4-241a-4624-b3ed-eafae12567d3 | en | body |
| 075cb5f4-241a-4624-b3ed-eafae12567d3 | en | tags |

As you can see, a translation for title in en is missing.

languages_storefront

| **created_at (timestamp)** | **updated_at (timestamp)** | **language_name (text)** | **language_code (text)** | **is_default (boolean)** | **online (boolean)** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6b0891ab-4acd-4ece-b6a4-727e736becd2 | 2023-04-28T13:00:03.086913+00:00 | 2023-04-28T13:00:03.086913+00:00 | Bulgarian | bg | TRUE |
| 87e339ea-dc89-4e41-bc5f-ff0607beb91f | 2023-05-18T13:02:09.832828+00:00 | 2023-05-18T13:02:09.832828+00:00 | English | en | FALSE |

I have created a view with this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cms_view AS
SELECT 
    cms.id,
    cms.slug,
    ls.language_code,
    coalesce(body.translation, default_body.translation) AS body,
    coalesce(title.translation, default_title.translation) AS title,
    coalesce(tags.translation, default_tags.translation) AS tags
FROM 
    cms
CROSS JOIN 
    languages_storefront ls
LEFT JOIN 
    cms_translations body ON body.id = cms.id AND body.attribute = 'body' AND body.language = ls.language_code
LEFT JOIN 
    cms_translations title ON title.id = cms.id AND title.attribute = 'title' AND title.language = ls.language_code
LEFT JOIN 
    cms_translations tags ON tags.id = cms.id AND tags.attribute = 'tags' AND tags.language = ls.language_code
LEFT JOIN 
    languages_storefront dls ON dls.is_default = true
LEFT JOIN 
    cms_translations default_body ON default_body.id = cms.id AND default_body.attribute = 'body' AND default_body.language = dls.language_code
LEFT JOIN 
    cms_translations default_title ON default_title.id = cms.id AND default_title.attribute = 'title' AND default_title.language = dls.language_code
LEFT JOIN 
    cms_translations default_tags ON default_tags.id = cms.id AND default_tags.attribute = 'tags' AND default_tags.language = dls.language_code;
```

This works as expected:
[image: Result from view]

Unfortunately,if I decide to add another attribute in the future, I will have to drop this view, and create another one with the new attribute, which is something I don't want to do.

The ultimate goals that I want to achieve are:

1. Be able to search by attributes. For example, I want to find all slugs (and their translations) where the title contains "cms".
2. Be able to show all slug titles. If there is no title for the language I need, the title in the default language (in this case Bulgarian) should be displayed.

I feel like this view is morally obsolete so to say, and there is a much more elegant solution out there, but I am not sure what it is.

Can you point me in the right direction?